# Local Notification - specific message for each day

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uilocalnotification

I have a little problem with local notifications. I am loading data from XML (datum - date and jmeno - name) and I need to set different message for notification.alertBody for specific date (for example, when is 16.10 and date loaded from XML is also 16.10, the message is "Feast has Havel" when is 17.10 and date from XML is also 17.10, the message is "Feast has is Hedwig," etc.) **if the application is turned off**. But I always receive notification.alertBody for date when the application was last running.

**There is my code for local notification:**

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM."];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay: 3];
[components setMonth: 7];
[components setYear: 2012];
[components setHour: 9];
[components setMinute: 54];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

for (i = 0; i < [self.slovoArray count]; i++)
{
     slova = [self.slovoArray objectAtIndex:i];

     if([slova.datum isEqual:dateString])
     {
     notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dnes je %@, státní svátek %@", slova.datum, slova.jmeno];
     }
         [notification  setFireDate: dateToFire];
         [notification setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
         [notification setRepeatInterval: NSCalendarUnitDay];
         notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
         notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
         [alertNotification setHidden:NO];
         }
 }
```

Comment: Be aware you can only set a maximum of 64 local notifications.

Comment: @rckoenes it is interesting, it does not help me too :(